# Invalid Element in selenium

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

Html Code:-

```
< input ng-model="ctrl.email" type="email" class="no-controls md-input ng-valid-email ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" required aria-label="Email" id="input_0" aria-invalid="false" style>
```

Selenium Code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","R://MCA//Rushabh//Setup//Testing Setup//Workspace//Selenium//src//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("URL");
    String email = "EMail";
    //WebElement Login =driver.findElement(ByClassName.className("segment-button"));
    WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
        ("no-controls.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.md-input.ng-empty.ng-valid-email.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required"));

    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('aria-invalid',true);",Login);
    Login.click();
}
```

Show Error in Selenium  :--

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"no-controls.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.md-input.ng-empty.ng-valid-email.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required"}

In Here Which Element I can Use For Testing............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Input «

```
<input ng-model="ctrl.email" type="email" class="no-controls md-input ng-valid-email ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" required aria-label="Email" id="input_0" aria-invalid="false" style>
```

Use any of the below [XPaths](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi):

```
//input[@id="input_0"]
//input[@type="email"]
//input[@type="email"][@aria-label="Email"]
```

Java code «

```java
int ELEMENT_WAIT_TIME_SEC = 60;
WebDriverWait explicitWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, ELEMENT_WAIT_TIME_SEC);

String locator = "//input[@type='email'][@aria-label='Email']";
By findBy = By.xpath( locator );
WebElement element = explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable( findBy ));

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('aria-invalid',true);", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use any one of below Selector for the `Login` element :**

1. id : `input_0`
2. xpath : `//input[@ng-model='ctrl.email']`
3. xpath : `//input[@type='email']`
4. xpath : `//input[@class='no-controls md-input ng-valid-email ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched']`
5. xpath : `//input[contains(@class,'ng-valid-email')]` 
   **Note :** here you can select any unique part of `class` value.
6. CSS/CSS selector : `input[class='no-controls md-input ng-valid-email ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched']`
7. CSS/CSS selector : `input[id='input_0']`

> **Final Note : Try this locators one by one. Please also check locators type like xpath, csspath**

[Example and Syntax](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/locators/)

Answer (score 0):

The css selector used here uses class
`no-controls.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.md-input.ng-empty.ng-valid-email.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required` which is not a good practice as the class can change according to the operation you perform on the input box like click, enter values etc.

Use id `#input_0` as the css selector

```
WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#input_0"));
```

or use aria-label `input[aria-label='Email']`

```
WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[aria-label='Email']"));
```